# Newsletter Subscriber Block on CMS Page not working

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter-subscriber, newsletter-block

The CMS Page, content is :

```
{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Its show the newsletter subscribe box, if add the email will not add to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call below way.. 
and  you have to enable the block in CMS -> Permissions (or add it, if it's not there).

The block name is of course: `newsletter/subscribe`

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

after check it

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong block, please change as follows:

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Comment: After change with your code my cms page look like empty even Text box also not visible. @HelgeB

Comment: than it might be a permission issue, check the answer of Rakesh Donga